# Creating a complex raw transaction

Tags: signrawtransaction, sighash

I'm using `createrawtransaction` to get a complex transaction of 2 inputs and two outputs as discussed here: https://developer.bitcoin.org/examples/transactions.html

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest createrawtransaction '''
     [
       {
         "txid": "'$UTXO1_TXID'",
         "vout": '$UTXO1_VOUT'
       },
       {
         "txid": "'$UTXO2_TXID'",
         "vout": '$UTXO2_VOUT'
       }
     ]
     ''' '''
     {
       "'$NEW_ADDRESS1'": 79.9999,
       "'$NEW_ADDRESS2'": 10
     }'''
0200000002ea34a15b5c6b1ec4d3e9d2a1fdb8f80c29b0aa93d1762359b5ba30b63437973a0000000000ffffffff3d38a74c05e837f87b7a0eb0b7c688396972ffe670fda8b7ba689c76acca24300000000000ffffffff02f028d6dc01000000160014e38542852b468886d97748b4ca3786387e9e9cdc00ca9a3b00000000160014f8dd22acbd0867c5ad1edd3c3ca6e8768845cb1d00000000
```

I assign this value to RAW_TX as described:
`RAW_TX=0200000002ea34a15b5c6b1ec4d3e9d2a1fdb8f80c29b0aa93d1762359b5ba30b63437973a0000000000ffffffff3d38a74c05e837f87b7a0eb0b7c688396972ffe670fda8b7ba689c76acca24300000000000ffffffff02f028d6dc01000000160014e38542852b468886d97748b4ca3786387e9e9cdc00ca9a3b00000000160014f8dd22acbd0867c5ad1edd3c3ca6e8768845cb1d00000000`

But then I run into problems. When using the private key I get an error saying it's not a valid sighash parameter. Since `signrawtransaction` is deprecated I'm using `signrawtransactionwithwallet`:

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest signrawtransactionwithwallet $RAW_TX '[]' '''
>     [
>       "'$UTXO1_PRIVATE_KEY'"
>     ]'''
error code: -1
error message:

    [
      "cUS7vndDv6nzJ3qEa5YG74dAzzEwTxRmbBFKXCn2fu2C4GSCbRKa"
    ] is not a valid sighash parameter.
```

I'm have no idea why it's not working. Please advise!

Comment: I tried adding more input but I get the following result:
```bitcoin-cli -regtest signrawtransactionwithwallet $RAW_TX '''
>     [
>       {
>         "txid": "'$UTXO1_TXID'",
>         "vout": '$UTXO1_VOUT',
>         "scriptPubKey": "'$UTXO1_OUTPUT_SCRIPT'",
>         "value": '$UTXO1_VALUE'
>       }
>     ]'''
error code: -3
error message:
Missing amount for CTxOut(nValue=21000000.00000000, scriptPubKey=001492718ece477c2053ebee50dc7e)
```